# Showing Announcement list in Custom Page in Sharepoint site

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, custom-pages

I am having a sharepoint site and i had  added  a custom aspx page and I want to show the announcement list items in that page. How to show the list items in a custom page ?. Helpful links and sample code would be helpful?

Comment: Jigs I tried this link http://suryapulipati.blogspot.in/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-show-add-new-item-or.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my requirement. I had used XsltListViewWebPart for displaying announcement list in custom application page. I would like to thank everyone who offered me their advice thanks a lot.

The following link did it for me

http://suryapulipati.blogspot.in/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-show-add-new-item-or.html

Answer (score 0):

Access Your custom page from the browser and Edit the page by clicking Site action > Edit Page. If you have a Web part Zone available in your page then

Click 'Add a webpart'(for webpart page) > Click 'Insert' tab in ribbon > Select 'WebPart' > List and libraries > select the announcement list and click OK.

This will add a web part of announcement list in your page.

But if you dont have the webpart zone then i am afraid it is not possible directly,

But you can use client object model for this visit this

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539350%28v=office.14%29.aspx